# DateTime Error with mysql using dotnet core

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, migration, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

Using Mysql with dotnet core API, my entity has on DateTime type column. In migration, it getting an error as

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL,
    `ModifiedAt` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: First, upload your full `CREATE` code.

Comment: I think your migrator is trying to create a datatype specification that your version of mysql cannot cope with. That's probably a bug/lack of support in the migrator that you'll have to work round with whatever option it has to pass a raw/custom type to the db. What version is your MySQL

Comment: My Server version: 5.5.51-38.1,
Packages: 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.3"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.1.1"/>

My Entity Code:
namespace Core.Entities
{
    public class Materials : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
       public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
       public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
    }
} 

My CLICMD:
dotnet ef migrations add MaterialsAdded -p Infrastructure -s API -o Data/Migrations

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the server version and type you are using, especially in your case, where you are using a very old (and unsupported) version of MySQL.

The easiest way to do this when adding migrations, is to implement the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TContext>` interface in a class, that will only be used when running the ef core tools:

```cs
public class BloggingDesignTimeContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<BloggingContext>
{
    public BloggingContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();

        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(
            "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=so62725308",
            mySqlOptions => mySqlOptions
                .ServerVersion(new Version(5, 5, 51), ServerType.MySql)); // <-- the server version

        return new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```